# Doctrine subquery in symfony2

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

i am using this query:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p
            FROM SnapRestBundle:Proxy p
            WHERE p.speed > 0 AND p.speed = ( SELECT MIN(p.speed) FROM p)');
$query->getSingleResult();
```

I am getting undefined class p, but if i define p again in the sub query, i get p is already defined?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you have used the `p` in already, in another query you have to use like below

```
 WHERE p.speed > 0 AND p.speed = ( SELECT MIN(d.speed) FROM p as d)');
```

instead of

```
WHERE p.speed > 0 AND p.speed = ( SELECT MIN(p.speed) FROM p)');
```

Comment: Getting:
Class 'p' is not defined.
I guess its from the assignment to d